# Need a Multi Div multiple image slider in one loop

Tags: jquery, html, slider, slidetoggle

Please help to create 4 div slider in one loop. Every div have multiple image this will sliding, In every div first image will sliding in 1st loop,then 2nd loop second image will sliding from every div this way loop will continue sliding...

https://jsfiddle.net/0L9ry37c/7/

```
<section class="slider-sec">
        <div class="slider-sec-wrapper">
            <div class="slider-sec-left">
                <div class="myslide">

                    <div class="rotating-home animated slideInLeft">
                        <img src="images/new-slider/s1.jpg" border="0"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="rotating-home animated slideInLeft">
                        <img src="images/new-slider/s2.jpg" border="0" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight">
                        <img src="images/new-slider/s4.jpg" border="0" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight">
                        <img src="images/new-slider/s3.jpg" border="0" />
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="slider-sec-right">
                <div class="sli-right-top">
                    <div class="sl-top-sli">
                        <div class="myslide">
                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/sli-right.jpg"  border="0" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/institute.jpg" border="0" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/institute.jpg" border="0" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/institute.jpg"  border="0" />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="sli-right-bottom">
                    <div class="sli-right-bottom-left">
                        <div class="myslide">
                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/s6.jpg" border="0" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInLeft">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/s5.jpg" border="0" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInLeft">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/s6.jpg" border="0" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInLeft">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/s6.jpg" border="0" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sli-right-bottom-right">
                        <div class="myslide">
                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInLeft">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/s6.jpg" border="0" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/s6.jpg" border="0" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/s5.jpg" border="0" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="rotating-home animated slideInRight">
                                <img src="images/new-slider/s5.jpg" border="0" />
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
   </section>
```

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var InfiniteRotator = {
            init: function () {
                //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
                var initialFadeIn = 1000;
                //interval between items (in milliseconds)
                var itemInterval = 1000;
                //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
                var fadeTime = 800;
                //count number of items
                var rotationLimit = $('div.myslide').length + 1;
                //set current item
                var currentItem = 0;
                //loop through the items
                var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function () {
                    $('div.myslide').eq(currentItem).find('.rotating-home').fadeToggle(fadeTime);
                    currentItem++;
                    if(currentItem == rotationLimit) currentItem = 0;
                }, itemInterval);
            }
        };
        InfiniteRotator.init();
    });
</script>
```

```
/*===========slider ===========*/

#page {
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}

.rotating-home img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}


#myslide{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;

}
.rotating-home {
    position: relative;


}
.rotating-home:first-of-type {
    display: none;
}
```

I need 4 div multiple image item sliding in one loop. 
In every div first item will be slide in different animation such as (left,right,up,down),
Then second loop second item will be sliding form 4 div,
third loop third item will be sliding form 4 div... this way the slider will be continue..

Comment: why not just use a slider that allows multiple images - eg https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: if you visit my website you will better understand why i need this slide.. (http://doptori.com/).